# Magento Customer Account payment methods

Tags: php, magento

I am working on project based on Magento. I need to put "Payment methods" section in customer account where I need to list all payment methods customer had for orders.

I can see payment method in each order in "Order history" but I need all of them on separate page and have ability to edit them.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have anything actionable? Some code, perhaps? Anything.

Comment: No code, just need an idea of how to get this. I googled but found nothing.